# Update document where all items in an array has the same value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

I am making a migration script where I need to update a status value on all documents where the items in an array has the same value

Data structure

```
[
{
  _id: 'asdasd',
  status: 'active',
  approvers: [
    {status: 'approved'},
    {status: 'approved'}
  ]
},
{
  _id: 'fghfgh',
  status: 'active',
  approvers: [
    {status: 'approved'},
    {status: 'awaiting_approval'},
  ]
}
]
```

So, in this case in want to update all documents to have status 'completed' where all approvers has status 'approved'

I haven't found a good way how to create a filter like this.

What I've currently tried to do is:

```
db.getCollection("assignmentRequest").aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            'approver.0.status': {$exists:true}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            approver: 1,
            status: 1,
            noOfApprovers: { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$approvers" }, then: { $size: "$approvers" }, else: 0}},
            noOfApproversThatHasApproved: { 
                $size: {$filter: { 
                    'input': '$approvers',
                    'as': 'approver',
                    'cond': {
                        '$and': [
                            {
                                    $eq: ['$$approver.status', 'approved'] 
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }}
            },
        },
    },
    { 
        $match: {$expr: { $eq: ["$noOfApprovers", "$noOfApproversThatHasApproved"] } }
    },
        {
        $set: {'status': 'completed'}
    },
    {
        $project: {_id:1, status:1 }
    },
    { 
        $merge: {into: 'assignmentRequests_copy', on: '_id', whenMatched: "replace" }
    }])
```

The filter works, but I can't get the status to update. I'm sure there are plenty of things worng with my query, but I feel like I am going down the wrong path and that there must be a simpler way of achieving this. Any pointers or help would be highly appreciated.

Edit:

After the update I want the documents to look like this:

```
{
  _id: 'asdasd',
  status: 'completed',
  approvers: [
    {status: 'approved'},
    {status: 'approved'}
  ]
},
{
  _id: 'fghfgh',
  status: 'active',
  approvers: [
    {status: 'approved'},
    {status: 'awaiting_approval'},
  ]
}
]
```

Comment: Would you show what you want your documents to look like after the update?

Comment: Updated the Question with desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it by using a pipeline in the update.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "approvers.status": "approved"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "status": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$approvers",
              "initialValue": true,
              "in": {
                "$and": [
                  "$$value",
                  {"$eq": ["$$this.status", "approved"]}
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "completed",
          "$status"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{"multi": true}
)
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NilxH7Z37bz).